# Using AngularJs "ng-style" within "ng-repeat" iteration

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-style

I am tring to conditionally set the colors of data elements in a table based on their value using ng-style. Each row of data is being generated using ng repeat.

So i have something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="payment in payments">
  <td ng-style="set_color({{payment}})">{{payment.number}}</td>
```

and a function in my controller that does something like:

```
$scope.set_color = function (payment) {
  if (payment.number > 50) {
    return '{color: red}'
  }
}
```

I have tried a couple different things. and even set the color as a data attribute in the payment object, however it seems I cant get ng-style to process data from the data bindings,
Does anyone know a way I could make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Don't use {{}}s inside an [Angular expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

```
<td ng-style="set_color(payment)">{{payment.number}}</td>
```

Return an object, not a string, from your function:

```
$scope.set_color = function (payment) {
  if (payment.number > 50) {
    return { color: "red" }
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/J5BGq/)

Answer (score 21):

use this code

```
<td style="color:{{payment.number>50?'red':'blue'}}">{{payment.number}}</td>
```

or

```
<td ng-style="{'color':(payment.number>50?'red':'blue')}">{{payment.number}}</td>
```

blue color for example

Answer (score 3):

It might help you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .yelloColor {
      background-color: gray;
    }
    .meterColor {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('ngStyleApp', []);
    app.controller('ngStyleCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.bar = "48%";
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ngStyleApp" ng-controller="ngStyleCtrl">
  <div class="yelloColor">
    <div class="meterColor" ng-style="{'width':bar}">
      <h4> {{bar}} DATA USED OF 100%</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```